# Error: instantiation policy violation: signature set did not satisfy policy

Tags: node.js, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I am facing this problem, below is the exact error:

```
Error: instantiation policy violation: signature set did not satisfy policy
at self._endorserClient.processProposal 
(/home/ubuntu/node_modules/fabric-client/lib/Peer.js:144:36)
at Object.onReceiveStatus 
(/home/ubuntu/node_modules/grpc/src/client_interceptors.js:1212:9)
at InterceptingListener._callNext 
(/home/ubuntu/node_modules/grpc/src/client_interceptors.js:568:42)
at InterceptingListener.onReceiveStatus 
(/home/ubuntu/node_modules/grpc/src/client_interceptors.js:618:8)
at callback 
(/home/ubuntu/node_modules/grpc/src/client_interceptors.js:847:24)
```

Here's my code, `helper` is the connection profile object of yaml.

```
var client = await helper.getClientForOrg(orgName, username);
var channel = client.getChannel(channelName);
var txId = client.newTransactionID(true);

var params = {
    targets: peerNames,
    chaincodePath: chaincodePath,
    chaincodeId: chaincodeName,
    chaincodeVersion: chaincodeVersion,
    chaincodeType: "node",
    channelNames: channelName
}
var deployResponse = await client.installChaincode(params);
console.log(deployResponse);

// send proposal to endorsing peers
var request = {
    targets: peerNames,
    chaincodeType: 'node',
    chaincodeId: chaincodeName,
    chaincodeVersion: chaincodeVersion,
    txId: txId,
    fcn: 'instantiate',
    args: args
}

let results = await channel.sendUpgradeProposal(request);
console.log(results);
```

This is the example of classic one member & one peer Fabric BlockChain (AWS managed) where using fabric-client library we are able to invoke chaincode and do the query as well. And it's working with any deployed chaincode. However if we try to instantiate / update a chain code using sendUpgradeProposal() method or sendInstantiateProposal() it's giving permission error, mentioned on the post. However installChaincode() method working fine.

Comment: Please don't write things in CAPS and please don't ask anyone here to do anything urgently. Your question is as urgent is as anyone else's

Comment: Please also explain what is the expected behavior, what is the actual one and where do you see the error. Otherwise, it's unclear what are you asking about. You should also show some debuggin attempts of yours: if you haven't tried anything, others won't be tempted to help.

Comment: hi @YakovL, this is the example of classic one member - one peer Fabric BlockChain where using fabric-client library we are able to invoke chaincode and do the query as well. And it's working with any deployed chaincode.

However if we try to instantiate / update a chain code using sendUpgradeProposal() method or sendInstantiateProposal() it's giving permission error, mentioned on the post. However installChaincode() method working fine.

Comment: great, please edit your post to include the main bits there. Well-put questions usually attract more attention and more useful responses